# How to build search with facetting over unknown/unspecified set of attributes/properties?

Tags: search, elasticsearch, search-engine, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm working on a product search engine with a big set of undefined products which is constantly growing. Each product has different attributes and at this time they're saved in an array of string key-value pairs like this:

```
"attributes": [
                    {
                        "key": "Producttype",
                        "value": "Headphones - 3.5 mm plug"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "Weight",
                        "value": "280 g"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "Soundmode",
                        "value": "Stereo"
                    },
                    ....
                ]
```

Each product has also a category. I'm using elasticsearch 2.4.x to persist data that i want to search on via spring-data-elasticsearch. It's possible to upgrade to the newest elasticsearch version if needed.

As you can see the attributes are really generic. It's also needed to use nested objects to be able to search on this attributes. I'm also thinking about preprocessing this attributes to a standardized format. For example the "Weight" key might be written in different forms like "Productweight" or "Weight of product". Because there are a lot of attributes and i wouldn't like to create a custom property/field for each one i thought about about mapping only the important ones (like weight) to a custom, own field and to map the other attributes like described above.

Now if someone searches for example "iphone" i would like to show some facettes on the left of the search result page. The facettes should differ if someone searches "Adidas shoes". Is this possible with the given format above using [nested objects](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html)? Is it possible to build the facettes dynamically regarding to the resultset elasticsearch is returning? E.g. the most common properties which all result products contain should be used to create facettes. Or do i have to persist some predefined filters/facettes on each category? I think that would be too much work and also doesn't work on search results where products can have different categories. What's the best practice to build a search feature with facetting on entities with n different properties that can grow in future?